# Where can I find collections of bibliography styles?

Tags: bibliographies, repositories

Is there a central 'warehouse' or, perhaps, a 'list of collections', of bibliography styles?

My preference is for BibLaTeX, but I'm sure answers for BibTeX would also be helpful.

I don't have any specific requirements, but I would be interested in (a) trying things out to see examples of bibliography formatting and (b) learning how to build such things myself.

Comment: Related question: [Verbal descriptions of bibliography styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24540/2693).

Comment: Five years on, would the downvoter care to stand up and say why, so we can learn and improve? Or are you just having a bad day and want to take it out on something not-too-important?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

- [bibstyles.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20180516185239/http://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/bibstyles.pdf) contains previews of reference lists and in-text citations for 44 styles.
- "[BibTeX Style Examples](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/%7Ekjt/software/latex/showbst.html)" contains previews of reference lists and in-text citations for 52 styles.
- "[BibTeX Bibliography Styles](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/632.htm%7EmainFrame)" contains previews of reference lists and in-text citations for 119 styles, displayed in separate files.
- "[Choosing a BibTeX style](http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html)" contains previews of 9 BibTeX styles, along with advice on how to choose a style according to the subject of the paper.

Comment: Thank you. The other answers were also very helpful -- my thanks to Andy and Schweinebacke -- but this one had the richest examples.

Comment: I recommonend the last link (http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html) as it provides a quick and neat overview.

Comment: The first link gives me a 404 error

Comment: When I click the first link, it prompts for a username and password.

Comment: The first link is fixed, however the third link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 18):

Sorry for my very (very) late answer, but I hope it would help anyway.
I've made a collection, named [Debibify](http://debibify.dorian-depriester.fr), of some bibTeX bibliography styles.

Comment: This is very useful!

Comment: You're never too late for the future :)

Answer (score 10):

As a starting point, I look on my own computer in the files that came with e.g. TexLive: `.../tex/latex/biblatex` and other stuff in `.../tex/latex` that starts with `biblatex`. I take the style that is closed to what I want and copy the file in the local directory and rename the `.cbx` file. In this case, I renamed it to `brent.cbx`. I further make an almost empty `.bbx` file like this one

```
%$Id: brent.bbx,v 0.1 2011/11/16 12:44:46 thomas stable $

\ProvidesFile{brent.bbx}
[\abx@bbxid $Id: brent.bbx,v 0.1 2011/11/16 12:44:46 thomas stable $]

\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric-comp}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1\isdot}}

\endinput
```

and name it `brent.bbx`. First, `numeric-comp` is taken and then I change something. In this case, I wanted the journal volume to be bold. So I changed

[image: normalcite]

to

[image: boldcite]

This way, I try to slowly come to the style I like.

My tex file:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=brent]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{cvpubs.bib}

\begin{document}
%
\fullcite{landau1937}
\end{document}
```

My bib file:

```
@article{landau1937,
author = {L. D. Landau}, 
title={On the Theory of Phase Transitions I},
journal = {Phys. Z. Sowjet.},
volume = {11},
pages = {545},
year = {1937}
}
```

I keep looking in the other files in the mentioned directory, if I am still missing something I want to change. The files that came with `biblatex` or rather TexLive were always good enough for me to find what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you, Andy for the effort you put into this. I particularly appreciate the way you pushed the envelope of my question a bit - very useful.

Comment: The collection from the Dorian [work/answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289490/116815) can be useful to find a style similar to our goal.