# reference formatting

Tags: biblatex

**I need my references to be formatted the same as in this image:**

[image]

**My .bib files look like this:**

```
@INCOLLECTION{Chandler2009,
  author = {Chandler, R.J.},
  title = {{Shorebirds of the Northern Hemisphere}},
  publisher = {Christopher Helm},
  year = {2009},
  address = {London},
  annote = {Whimbrel and Curlew account},
  file = {:Users/rossahmed/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Chandler - 2009 - Shorebirds of the Northern Hemisphere.pdf:pdf}
}

@BOOK{EngelmoerM&Roselaar1998,
  title = {{Geographical Variation in Waders}},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {1998},
  author = {Engelmoer, M. \&  Roselaar, C.S.},
  pages = {214--223},
  annote = {Curlew and Whimbrel section},
  file = {:Users/rossahmed/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Engelmoer, M \& Roselaar - 1998 - Geographical Variation in Waders.pdf:pdf}
}

@BOOK{PraterT1977,
  title = {{Guide to the Identification and Ageing of Holarctic Waders}},
  publisher = {BTO},
  year = {1977},
  author = {{Prater, T.}, Marchant.J. \& Vuorien, J.},
  address = {Tring},
  annote = {Curlew and Whimbrel section},
  file = {:Users/rossahmed/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Prater, T - 1977 - Guide to the Identification and Ageing of Holarctic Waders.pdf:pdf}
}
```

**Unfortunately, as I'm a beginner, the following code is as close as ive got to producing the desired results:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{CU1.1jabref.bib}
\begin{document}

This is my text \cite{EngelmoerM&Roselaar1998}

This is more text \cite{Chandler2009}

This is even more text \cite{PraterT1977}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**How can I produce desired reference formatting?**

Comment: Tou haven't chosen a bibliography style. Have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles) and the answers therein.

Comment: @Vivi Yes he has, `style=authoryear`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I had no idea you could pass that as an argument there! See, even wrong comments are useful (in this case useful to me, not to him). Cheers for pointing it out.

Comment: @Vivi `biblatex` works a little bit different to the "old" `bibtex` way. See e.g. the questions mentioned [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions/2428#2428).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I use bibtex, and I haven't yet switched. I will definitely look into it during the Christmas/New Years break! Thanks again :)

Comment: Assuming the journal or university to which you have to submit this hasn't published its own style you're going to have to tweak with it yourself to get the desired output.

Comment: @RossAhmed -- will your bibliography only contain journal articles?  If so, your style will be easy to implement; if not, you need to provide a more detailed specification to get the help you need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the journal or university to which you have to submit this hasn't published its own style you're going to have to tweak with it yourself to get the desired output.

You don't need (and shouldn't actually) try to generate a whole new style from scratch but you could make a new style based on an existing one.

What you'll need to do is to generate a `.bbx` file and possibly also a `.cbx` file, say `my_style.bbx`. The first controls the bibliography list and the latter controls the citation style in the text. The `.bbx` file should start with `\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear}` (or any other style you'd like to base on) and in the `.cbx` file you should place `\RequireCitationStyle{authoryear}`.

And then make your tweaks in the rest of the file.
[Here's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) a good place to start learning how to do that.

I went through the same process when trying to generate some citation styles for journals in microbiology. You can see my styles [here](https://github.com/roey-angel/BIBEMME). This should give you a good start.