# References aren't printed in PDF

Tags: bibtex, pdf, texmaker

My references aren't listed in my PDF file and all cites have a '?' symbol instead a number even in Texmaker my cites are selectable.

Here my tex file:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
```

...

```
efficient inference in universal model classes \cite{PPWIKI}. On the other hand,
```

...

```
\bibliographystyle{style}
\bibliography{literature}
\end{document}
```

My bibtex file:

```
@online{PPWIKI,
author = {PROBABILISTIC-PROGRAMMING.org},
title = {The probabilistic programming approach},
year = {2014},
url = {http://probabilistic-programming.org/wiki/Home},
}
```

I following "Quickbuild" in Texmaker (texmaker v4.2 + miktex v2.9.5 on Windows 8):

> PdfLaTex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTex (x2) + View Pdf

Any idea?

Comment: `style` is not a valid bibliography style as far as I know. See [Where can I find collections of bibliography styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles) for many valid possibilities.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I identified 2 problems in your MWE:

1. As @Paul Gessler said, in **\bibliographystyle{style}**, "style" is not a valid bibliography style. To read more about the different bibliography styles, check the link he provided or [this one](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Bibliography_styles).
2. I couldn't compile your **literature.bib** file, because the last element in the bibitem has a colon at the end (**" url = {http://probabilistic-programming.org/wiki/Home}, "**)

Fixing these two aspects I was able to compile your code.

Here is is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

efficient inference in universal model classes \cite{PPWIKI}. On the other hand,

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{literature}
\end{document}



###literature.bib

@online{PPWIKI,
author = {PROBABILISTIC-PROGRAMMING.org},
title = {The probabilistic programming approach},
year = {2014},
url = {http://probabilistic-programming.org/wiki/Home}
}
```

And here is the end result:

[image]