# How to display in-text citation in the "Author Year: page" format?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, quoting

I was wondering how to make LaTex display my in-text citations in the following format:
"some text some text some text **(Name 2015: 23)**."

I'm using the natbib-package and the bibliography style in my document is 
/bibliographystyle{authordate3}. So, when I cite in the text I get this:

"some text some text some text **(Name, 2015, p. 23)**."

I'm a new LaTex user (just started using it a couple of weeks ago!), and till now I've managed to solve my problems just googling them, but this time it wont work, because I don't know how is the name of this style and that's why I couldn't look for it.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please refer to [Where can I find collections of bibliography styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35040/35864) and related questions to find a list of `.bst` and pick one you like. You might also want to consider switching to `biblatex`, see [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it! this: `\bibpunct[: ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}` before `\begin{document}` solved everything!