# Bibliography style - is there a repository?

Tags: bibliographies

I need to format the reference list in my article. There is no available bst file (that I am aware of) that would produce the format that is required. I think it is best to find the closest style to that, and the manually modify the rest?

After spending about one hour searching for this stuff, it turns out that it is virtually impossible to find a source that gives you an example of the styles produced by different bst-files, let alone let you download any of these (I am using Sharelatex).

The format I need is: Lastname, F. "Title." *Journal*, Vol. (Year), pages.

Can anyone point to a bst file that produces an outcome fairly close to this one? I can then modify the rest. Thanks!

Comment: I would ask the journal editors for advice first. They know about that stuff.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles. But imho adapting biblatex is easier than adapting (or creating with makebst) a bibtex style.

Answer (score 1):

This should hopefully get you quite close:

In the preamble

```
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,firstinits=true,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<your_bib_file>.bib}
```

In a `biblatex.cfg` file in the same directory as your `.tex` file:

```
%Don't print issue number
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{number}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}{}
      {\printtext{%
     \printfield{labelyear}%
     \printfield{extrayear}}}}


%uncomment the next line to put "Vol." before volume number
%\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol.~#1}


% Comma before journal volume
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\space}%
{\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}}
}


\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
      \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseauthor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
      }
        {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
           {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\addspace}}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
```