# Which bibliography style is like this?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I want to create bibliography by `Bibtex` which is exactly the following format:

```
[1] Author: \textit{title} journal abbreviations
\textbf{vol}, pages (year)
```

**Output**

---

[1] Author: *title*, J. Ab, **70**, 100-200 (2017)

---

Is there an appropriate style file?

**Update:** (after  Johannes_B comment)

The format of bibliography for book is as follow:

```
  [1] Author: \textit{title} Book series, 
      vol. 25, publisher, pages (year)
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{birkjour}

\begin{document}

In \cite{1} and \cite{2} we have:
$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
\bibliographystyle{siam}    %must be changed to a benefit style 
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

where `biblio.bib` is:

```
@article{1,
 title={first article},
 author={Name},
 journal={journal of geometry},
 volume={18},
 number={1},
 pages={229--238},
 year={2010}
  }

@article{2,
 title={second article},
 author={Name},
 journal={journal of geometry},
 volume={18},
 number={2},
 pages={239--248},
 year={2010}
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: It should be `plain`I think. It's the default with `biblatex`.

Comment: Plain does not have parenthesis for year and volume not  bold.

Comment: The question is too unspecific for an answer. Usually, a book is put down differently than a journal or a conference entry.

Comment: I want the bibliography style of https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00022-016-0343-1.pdf

Comment: @C.F.G.: That's easy to customise with `biblatex`.

Comment: Can you explain how do it?

Comment: In this example, titles of articles are not in italic.

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable example?

Comment: You can download birkjour.cls from here: http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/814998/application/zip/birkjour.zip

Comment: The stylistic information you've provided so far still isn't sufficiently detailed. E.g., in addition to the entry types `@article` and `@book`, what about the following types: `@misc`, `@techreport`, `@unpublished` -- and a few others more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the examples linked from [Where can I find collections of bibliography styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles)
`spiebib.bst` seems pretty close.

**Update:** The style `splncs.bst` is as you want.

Comment: I cant find a benefit style, because after author name must be ":".

Comment: Thanks. I find it. The style `splncs.bst` is exactly that I want. see for example https://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/splncs.pdf