# biblatex, bibtex and citation styles

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am using Miktex engine for Linux, which unfortunately does not support `biber` (for now). For this reason, I have to set `backend=bibtex` option in `biblatex`.

So, my question is how can I change citation style (e.g. to author-year) in the following set up?

```
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
natbib,
style=?
]{biblatex}
```

`

Comment: Did you checked here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles

Comment: the problem is not only which style to choose,but how to set up my preamble...

Comment: \bibliographystyle command does not work since i load biblatex package. i would appreciate if you could provide a mwe

Comment: Ok. Removing my previous comment. I thought it would accept bibliographystyle command. Why you have to use biber and not just bibtex command? Does it have to do with Miktex?

Comment: yes exactly...i cannot use biber, since miktex does not support it in the linux version

Comment: Ahnyway... I found that: "Please beware that MiKTeX for Linux is still in an experimental stage"... I think you should have a really important reason to not use texlive or something original about TeX on your linux. And If you can not use biber don't use it... Use bibtex if this software you use have such option. But I would suggest a distro like texlive or anyway something compatible with linux

Comment: Have you been taken a look at the manual? `authoryear`?

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't be able to use biber. If miktex doesn't provide it get the binary from eg texlive and put it in your path.

Comment: Or get the binary from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/current/binaries/Linux/.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i didn't know that i could do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed by the MikTeX developer on GitHub a Biber package is not yet available for MikTeX on Linux https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/2

The download page (https://miktex.org/download) states for Linux

> Please beware that MiKTeX for Linux is still in an experimental stage.

So if you need a full and stable TeX distribution on Linux for production then you should probably not use MikTeX since it is still experimental. Use the tried and tested TeX live (maybe in vanilla for newest updates - [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)) instead. Biber is available there and is kept in sync with `biblatex`.

If you absolutely must use the experimental MikTeX on Linux and must use Biber, you can get the Binaries from SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/current/binaries/Linux/ Note that you absolutely need to make sure that the versions of `biblatex` installed via MikTeX and Biber installed manually are compatible. Remember to manually update Biber after each (semi-)automatic update of `biblatex`.

---

To answer the question you posted. When you use BibTeX as backend you change your `biblatex` style exactly the same way you would when you use Biber. (You still can't use `.bst` styles, since `biblatex` is incompatible with them. no matter what backend you use.)

So if with Biber you used `\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib, style=authoryear]{biblatex}`, with BibTeX it is

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, natbib, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

Note that since BibTeX is considered a legacy backend, some features may not be available with BibTeX. The full set of features is only supported by Biber. That is why you should prefer Biber over BibTeX.