# Bibliography: change labelling from [part of the author´s name, year] to [number]

Tags: bibliographies

I have a problem with labelling items - they are labelled in the form [part of the author´s name, year] and I need normal numbered form. In the example below I have [KA00] but I need just [1].Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

It looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

\cite{review}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{citation} 

\end{document}
```

and citation.bib :

```
@article{review,
title = "Magnetron sputtering: a review of recent developments and 
applications",
journal = "Vacuum",
volume = "56",
number = "3",
pages = "159 - 172",
year = "2000",
issn = "0042-207X",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/S0042-207X(99)00189-X",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042207X9900189X",
author = "P.J Kelly and R.D Arnell",
keywords = "Closed-field unbalanced magnetron sputtering",
keywords = "Pulsed sputtering",
keywords = "Variable magnetrons"
}
```

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{plain}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`. See also [Where can I find collections of bibliography styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35040/35864), https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/bibtex_bibliography_styles

Comment: Welcome, you probably want to replace `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` by `\bibliographystyle{plain}` or `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`.

Comment: I tried to change \bibliographystyle{alpha} by \bibliographystyle{plain} but it does not work as I want - my problem is still here....

Comment: Did you compile again with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX?