# Looking for a bibliography style near to the one used by maa

Tags: bibliographies, journal-publishing, journal

I would be grateful if someone can present a known bibliography/BibTeX style (bst file) which is a good approximation of the style proposed by [maa](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/MAA_ReferenceGuide.pdf) (recently used by some journals like [The American Mathematical Monthly](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly)).

Comment: It seems that `biblatex-chem` has a `chem-biochem` bibliography style not too far from `maa`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, I would look at it. Meanwhile I wait for other suggestions.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles

Comment: You could employ the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package, to create a bespoke bibliography style that implements all formatting requirements exactly.

Answer (score 5):

```
ENTRY
 { address
 author
 booktitle
 chapter
 doi
 edition
 editor
 eid
 howpublished
 institution
 journal
 key
 month
 note
 number
 organization
 pages
 publisher
 school
 series
 title
 type
 volume
 year
}
 {}
 { label }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
 #1 'mid.sentence :=
 #2 'after.sentence :=
 #3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
 output.state mid.sentence =
 { ", " * write$ }
 { output.state after.block =
 { add.period$ write$
 newline$
 "\newblock " write$
}
 { output.state before.all =
 'write$
 { add.period$ " " * write$ }
 if$
}
 if$
 mid.sentence 'output.state :=
}
 if$
 s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
 'pop$
 'output.nonnull
 if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
 duplicate$ empty$
 { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
 'output.nonnull
 if$
}
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
 write$
 newline$
}
FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
 'skip$
 { after.block 'output.state := }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
 'skip$
 { output.state before.all =
 'skip$
 { after.sentence 'output.state := }
 if$
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{ " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}
FUNCTION {date.block}
{
 new.block
}
FUNCTION {not}
{ { #0 }
 { #1 }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {and}
{ 'skip$
 { pop$ #0 }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {or}
{ { pop$ #1 }
 'skip$
 if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
 'skip$
 'new.block
 if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
 swap$ empty$
 and
 'skip$
 'new.block
 if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
 'skip$
 'new.sentence
 if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
 swap$ empty$
 and
 'skip$
 'new.sentence
 if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
 { pop$ "" }
 'skip$
 if$
}
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
 { pop$ "" }
 { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
 { "~" }
 { " " }
 if$
 swap$
}
FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }
FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }
 % Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
 % Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
 % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }
FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "eds." }
FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "ed." }
FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }
FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "ed." }
FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "vol." }
FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }
FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "no." }
FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "no." }
FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }
FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pp." }
FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "p." }
FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chap." }
FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Tech. Rep." }
FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }
FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "Ph.D. thesis" }
FUNCTION {bbl.first}
{ "1st" }
FUNCTION {bbl.second}
{ "2nd" }
FUNCTION {bbl.third}
{ "3rd" }
FUNCTION {bbl.fourth}
{ "4th" }
FUNCTION {bbl.fifth}
{ "5th" }
FUNCTION {bbl.st}
{ "st" }
FUNCTION {bbl.nd}
{ "nd" }
FUNCTION {bbl.rd}
{ "rd" }
FUNCTION {bbl.th}
{ "th" }
MACRO {jan} {"Jan."}
MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}
MACRO {mar} {"Mar."}
MACRO {apr} {"Apr."}
MACRO {may} {"May"}
MACRO {jun} {"Jun."}
MACRO {jul} {"Jul."}
MACRO {aug} {"Aug."}
MACRO {sep} {"Sep."}
MACRO {oct} {"Oct."}
MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}
MACRO {dec} {"Dec."}
FUNCTION {eng.ord}
{ duplicate$ "1" swap$ *
 #-2 #1 substring$ "1" =
 { bbl.th * }
 { duplicate$ #-1 #1 substring$
 duplicate$ "1" =
 { pop$ bbl.st * }
 { duplicate$ "2" =
 { pop$ bbl.nd * }
 { "3" =
 { bbl.rd * }
 { bbl.th * }
 if$
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Comput. Surv."}
MACRO {acta} {"Acta Inf."}
MACRO {cacm} {"Commun. ACM"}
MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM J. Res. Dev."}
MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Syst.~J."}
MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Trans. Software Eng."}
MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Trans. Comput."}
MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Trans. Comput. Aid. Des."}
MACRO {ipl} {"Inf. Process. Lett."}
MACRO {jacm} {"J.~ACM"}
MACRO {jcss} {"J.~Comput. Syst. Sci."}
MACRO {scp} {"Sci. Comput. Program."}
MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM J. Comput."}
MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Trans. Comput. Syst."}
MACRO {tods} {"ACM Trans. Database Syst."}
MACRO {tog} {"ACM Trans. Graphic."}
MACRO {toms} {"ACM Trans. Math. Software"}
MACRO {toois} {"ACM Trans. Office Inf. Syst."}
MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Trans. Progr. Lang. Syst."}
MACRO {tcs} {"Theor. Comput. Sci."}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
 duplicate$ missing$
 {
 pop$ pop$
 ""
}
 { duplicate$ empty$
 {
 swap$ pop$
}
 { swap$
 pop$
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.warn}
{ swap$
 duplicate$ missing$
 {
 swap$ "missing " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$ pop$
 ""
}
 { duplicate$ empty$
 {
 swap$ "empty " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$
}
 { swap$
 pop$
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

STRINGS { bibinfo}
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
 duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
 's :=
 "" 't :=
 #1 'nameptr :=
 s num.names$ 'numnames :=
 numnames 'namesleft :=
 { namesleft #0 > }
 { s nameptr
 "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}"
 format.name$
 bibinfo bibinfo.check
 't :=
 nameptr #1 >
 {
 namesleft #1 >
 { ", " * t * }
 {
 s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
 { 't := }
 { pop$ }
 if$
 "," *
 t "others" =
 {
 " " * bbl.etal *
}
 { " " * t * }
 if$
}
 if$
}
 't
 if$
 nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
 namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
}
 while$
 } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
 'bibinfo :=
 duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
 's :=
 "" 't :=
 #1 'nameptr :=
 s num.names$ 'numnames :=
 numnames 'namesleft :=
 { namesleft #0 > }
 { s nameptr
 "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
 format.name$
 bibinfo bibinfo.check
 't :=
 nameptr #1 >
 {
 namesleft #1 >
 { ", " * t * }
 {
 s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
 { 't := }
 { pop$ }
 if$
 "," *
 t "others" =
 {
 " " * bbl.etal *
}
 { " " * t * }
 if$
}
 if$
}
 't
 if$
 nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
 namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
}
 while$
 } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
}
FUNCTION {get.bbl.editor}
{ editor num.names$ #1 > 'bbl.editors 'bbl.editor if$ }
FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
 {
 "," *
 " " *
 get.bbl.editor
 *
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
 { "" }
 {
 new.block
 "\doi{" doi * "}" *
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
 { "" }
 { note #1 #1 substring$
 duplicate$ "{" =
 'skip$
 { output.state mid.sentence =
 { "l" }
 { "u" }
 if$
 change.case$
}
 if$
 note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
 duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
 { "t" change.case$ }
 if$
 "title" bibinfo.check
}
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
 "\bibitem{" write$
 cite$ write$
 "}" write$
 newline$
 ""
 before.all 'output.state :=
}
FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
 't :=
 ""
 { t empty$ not }
 { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
 { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
 { "--" *
 t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
}
 { { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
 { "-" *
 t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
}
 while$
}
 if$
}
 { t #1 #1 substring$ *
 t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
}
 if$
}
 while$
}
FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in capitalize
 ":" *
 " " * }
FUNCTION {format.date}
{
 ""
 duplicate$ empty$
 year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
 { swap$ 'skip$
 { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
 if$
 *
}
 { swap$ 'skip$
 {
 swap$
 " " * swap$
}
 if$
 *
}
 if$
 duplicate$ empty$
 'skip$
 {
 before.all 'output.state :=
 " (" swap$ * ")" *
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
 duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
 {
 emphasize
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
 'pop$
 { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
 { "" }
 { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
 "volume" bibinfo.check * *
 series "series" bibinfo.check
 duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
 { swap$ bbl.of space.word * swap$
 emphasize * }
 if$
 "volume and number" number either.or.check
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
 { number empty$
 { series field.or.null }
 { series empty$
 { number "number" bibinfo.check }
 { output.state mid.sentence =
 { bbl.number }
 { bbl.number capitalize }
 if$
 number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
 bbl.in space.word *
 series "series" bibinfo.check *
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
 { "" }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {is.num}
{ chr.to.int$
 duplicate$ "0" chr.to.int$ < not
 swap$ "9" chr.to.int$ > not and
}
FUNCTION {extract.num}
{ duplicate$ 't :=
 "" 's :=
 { t empty$ not }
 { t #1 #1 substring$
 t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
 duplicate$ is.num
 { s swap$ * 's := }
 { pop$ "" 't := }
 if$
}
 while$
 s empty$
 'skip$
 { pop$ s }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {convert.edition}
{ extract.num "l" change.case$ 's :=
 s "first" = s "1" = or
 { bbl.first 't := }
 { s "second" = s "2" = or
 { bbl.second 't := }
 { s "third" = s "3" = or
 { bbl.third 't := }
 { s "fourth" = s "4" = or
 { bbl.fourth 't := }
 { s "fifth" = s "5" = or
 { bbl.fifth 't := }
 { s #1 #1 substring$ is.num
 { s eng.ord 't := }
 { edition 't := }
 if$
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
 if$
 t
}
FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
 {
 convert.edition
 output.state mid.sentence =
 { "l" }
 { "t" }
 if$ change.case$
 "edition" bibinfo.check
 " " * bbl.edition *
}
 if$
}
INTEGERS { multiresult }
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
 #0 'multiresult :=
 { multiresult not
 t empty$ not
 and
}
 { t #1 #1 substring$
 duplicate$ "-" =
 swap$ duplicate$ "," =
 swap$ "+" =
 or or
 { #1 'multiresult := }
 { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
 if$
}
 while$
 multiresult
}
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
 { duplicate$ multi.page.check
 {
 bbl.pages swap$
 n.dashify
}
 {
 bbl.page swap$
}
 if$
 tie.or.space.prefix
 "pages" bibinfo.check
 * *
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
 { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
 { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
 {
 ": " *
 swap$
 n.dashify
 "pages" bibinfo.check
 *
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.eid}
{ eid "eid" bibinfo.check
 duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
 { swap$ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
 {
 ": " *
}
 if$
 swap$ *
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
 duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
 {
 "volume" bibinfo.check
}
 if$
 number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
 {
 swap$ duplicate$ empty$
 { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
 'skip$
 if$
 swap$
 "(" swap$ * ")" *
}
 if$ *
}
FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
 { "" }
 { type empty$
 { bbl.chapter }
 { type "l" change.case$
 "type" bibinfo.check
}
 if$
 chapter tie.or.space.prefix
 "chapter" bibinfo.check
 * *
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.booktitle}
{
 booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check
 emphasize
}
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
 {
 editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
 {
 "," *
 " " *
 get.bbl.editor
 ", " *
 * swap$
 * }
 if$
 word.in swap$ *
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
 month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
 and and and and and
 key empty$ not and
 { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
 'skip$
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type duplicate$ empty$
 'pop$
 { swap$ pop$
 "t" change.case$ "type" bibinfo.check
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ number "number" bibinfo.check
 type duplicate$ empty$
 { pop$ bbl.techrep }
 'skip$
 if$
 "type" bibinfo.check
 swap$ duplicate$ empty$
 { pop$ "t" change.case$ }
 { tie.or.space.prefix * * }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
 key duplicate$ empty$
 { pop$
 journal duplicate$ empty$
 { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref * warning$ }
 { "journal" bibinfo.check emphasize word.in swap$ * }
 if$
}
 { word.in swap$ * " " *}
 if$
 " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
 "editor" bibinfo.check
 editor num.names$ duplicate$
 #2 >
 { pop$
 "editor" bibinfo.check
 " " * bbl.etal
 *
}
 { #2 <
 'skip$
 { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
 {
 "editor" bibinfo.check
 " " * bbl.etal
 *
}
 {
 bbl.and space.word
 * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
 "editor" bibinfo.check
 *
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume duplicate$ empty$
 { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
 pop$ word.in
}
 { bbl.volume
 capitalize
 swap$ tie.or.space.prefix "volume" bibinfo.check * * bbl.of space.word *
}
 if$
 editor empty$
 editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
 or
 { key empty$
 { series empty$
 { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
 crossref * warning$
 "" *
}
 { series emphasize * }
 if$
}
 { key * }
 if$
}
 { format.crossref.editor * }
 if$
 " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
 editor empty$
 editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
 or
 { key empty$
 { format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$
 { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
 crossref * warning$
}
 { word.in swap$ * }
 if$
}
 { word.in key * " " *}
 if$
}
 { word.in format.crossref.editor * " " *}
 if$
 " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
 ""
 address empty$ t empty$ and
 'skip$
 {
 address "address" bibinfo.check *
 t empty$
 'skip$
 { address empty$
 'skip$
 { ": " * }
 if$
 t *
}
 if$
}
 if$
}
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}
FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
}
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
 format.authors "author" output.check
 format.date "year" output.check
 date.block
 format.title "title" output.check
 new.block
 crossref missing$
 {
 journal
 "journal" bibinfo.check
 emphasize
 "journal" output.check
 format.vol.num.pages output
}
 { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
}
 if$
 eid empty$
 { format.journal.pages }
 { format.journal.eid }
 if$
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
 author empty$
 { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
}
 { format.authors output.nonnull
 crossref missing$
 { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
 'skip$
 if$
}
 if$
 format.date "year" output.check
 date.block
 format.btitle "title" output.check
 crossref missing$
 { format.bvolume output
 new.block
 format.number.series output
 new.sentence
 format.publisher.address output
}
 {
 new.block
 format.book.crossref output.nonnull
}
 if$
 format.edition output
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
 format.authors output
 format.date output
 date.block
 format.title "title" output.check
 new.block
 howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
 address "address" bibinfo.check output
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
 author empty$
 { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
}
 { format.authors output.nonnull
 crossref missing$
 { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
 'skip$
 if$
}
 if$
 format.date "year" output.check
 date.block
 format.btitle "title" output.check
 crossref missing$
 {
 format.bvolume output
 format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
 new.block
 format.number.series output
 new.sentence
 format.publisher.address output
}
 {
 format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
 new.block
 format.book.crossref output.nonnull
}
 if$
 format.edition output
 format.pages "pages" output.check
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
 format.authors "author" output.check
 format.date "year" output.check
 date.block
 format.title "title" output.check
 new.block
 crossref missing$
 { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
 format.bvolume output
 format.number.series output
 format.chapter.pages output
 new.sentence
 format.publisher.address output
 format.edition output
}
 { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
 format.chapter.pages output
}
 if$
 format.pages "pages" output.check
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
 format.authors "author" output.check
 format.date "year" output.check
 date.block
 format.title "title" output.check
 new.block
 crossref missing$
 { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
 format.bvolume output
 format.number.series output
 new.sentence
 publisher empty$
 { format.organization.address output }
 { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
 format.publisher.address output
}
 if$
}
 { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
}
 if$
 format.pages "pages" output.check
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }
FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
 author empty$
 { organization "organization" bibinfo.check
 duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
 { output
 address "address" bibinfo.check output
}
 if$
}
 { format.authors output.nonnull }
 if$
 format.date output
 date.block
 format.btitle "title" output.check
 author empty$
 { organization empty$
 {
 address new.block.checka
 address "address" bibinfo.check output
}
 'skip$
 if$
}
 {
 organization address new.block.checkb
 organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
 address "address" bibinfo.check output
}
 if$
 format.edition output
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
 format.authors "author" output.check
 format.date "year" output.check
 date.block
 format.btitle
 "title" output.check
 new.block
 bbl.mthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
 school "school" bibinfo.warn output
 address "address" bibinfo.check output
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
 format.authors output
 format.date output
 title howpublished new.block.checkb
 format.title output
 howpublished new.block.checka
 howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
 empty.misc.check
}
FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
 format.authors "author" output.check
 format.date "year" output.check
 date.block
 format.btitle
 "title" output.check
 new.block
 bbl.phdthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
 school "school" bibinfo.warn output
 address "address" bibinfo.check output
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
 editor empty$
 { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
}
 { format.editors output.nonnull }
 if$
 format.date "year" output.check
 date.block
 format.btitle "title" output.check
 format.bvolume output
 format.number.series output
 editor empty$
 { publisher empty$
 'skip$
 {
 new.sentence
 format.publisher.address output
}
 if$
}
 { publisher empty$
 {
 new.sentence
 format.organization.address output }
 {
 new.sentence
 organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
 format.publisher.address output
}
 if$
}
 if$
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
 format.authors "author" output.check
 format.date "year" output.check
 date.block
 format.title
 "title" output.check
 new.block
 format.tr.number output.nonnull
 institution "institution" bibinfo.warn output
 address "address" bibinfo.check output
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note output
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
 format.authors "author" output.check
 format.date output
 date.block
 format.title "title" output.check
 format.doi output
 new.block
 format.note "note" output.check
 fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
 "l" change.case$
}
INTEGERS { len }
FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
 'len :=
 s #1 len substring$ =
 { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
 's
 if$
}
FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
 #1 'nameptr :=
 ""
 s num.names$ 'numnames :=
 numnames 'namesleft :=
 { namesleft #0 > }
 { s nameptr
 "{ll{ }}{ f{ }}{ jj{ }}"
 format.name$ 't :=
 nameptr #1 >
 {
 " " *
 namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
 { "zzzzz" 't := }
 'skip$
 if$
 t sortify *
}
 { t sortify * }
 if$
 nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
 namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
}
 while$
}
FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
 "A " #2
 "An " #3
 "The " #4 t chop.word
 chop.word
 chop.word
 sortify
 #1 global.max$ substring$
}
FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
 { key empty$
 { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
 ""
}
 { key sortify }
 if$
}
 { author sort.format.names }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
 { editor empty$
 { key empty$
 { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
 ""
}
 { key sortify }
 if$
}
 { editor sort.format.names }
 if$
}
 { author sort.format.names }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {author.organization.sort}
{ author empty$
 { organization empty$
 { key empty$
 { "to sort, need author, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
 ""
}
 { key sortify }
 if$
}
 { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
 if$
}
 { author sort.format.names }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {editor.organization.sort}
{ editor empty$
 { organization empty$
 { key empty$
 { "to sort, need editor, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
 ""
}
 { key sortify }
 if$
}
 { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
 if$
}
 { editor sort.format.names }
 if$
}
FUNCTION {presort}
{ type$ "book" =
 type$ "inbook" =
 or
 'author.editor.sort
 { type$ "proceedings" =
 'editor.organization.sort
 { type$ "manual" =
 'author.organization.sort
 'author.sort
 if$
}
 if$
}
 if$
 " "
 *
 year field.or.null sortify
 *
 " "
 *
 title field.or.null
 sort.format.title
 *
 #1 entry.max$ substring$
 'sort.key$ :=
}
ITERATE {presort}
SORT
STRINGS { longest.label }
INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }
FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
 #1 'number.label :=
 #0 'longest.label.width :=
}
FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
 number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
 label width$ longest.label.width >
 { label 'longest.label :=
 label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
}
 'skip$
 if$
}
EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}
ITERATE {longest.label.pass}
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
 'skip$
 { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
 if$
 "\begin{thebibliography}{" longest.label * "}" *
 write$ newline$
 "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax"
 write$ newline$
 " \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}#1}\else"
 write$ newline$
 " \providecommand{\doi}{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}\begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi"
 write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
 "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

Comment: This bst file is based on the use of `makebst` as Mico suggested. This is a good approximation of the style suggested by maa.

Comment: How would one modify the code above so that the numbers are bracketed in the reference list?

Comment: @PietroPaparella In order that the numbers are bracketed in the reference list, I think adding `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{[#1]}
\makeatother
` to the preamble can do the job.

Comment: Indeed, but it would be better to have a mad.bst file that had all the features.

Comment: @PietroPaparella This is less to have with bst file. The style sheet of maa (see https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/maa-monthly.sty) causes numbers without brackets. In fact this is their style. If you look at their sty file, there is explicitly `\def\@biblabel#1{#1.}` which forces numbering without brackets.