# IEEEConf Bibliography does not work

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am using the template entitled "Preparation of Papers for IEEE Sponsored Conferences \& Symposia", in the overleaf. I am trying to use a bibtex file, named ref.bib instead of the "bib items".

In the end of document, I put the following:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEconf}
\bibliography{ref}
```

But the section References does not appear. I imagine that is lacking the IEEEconf.bst file, but I do not know where I can find the correct one.

Here is the warning showed:

> (no line number): This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
>   Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009 The
>   top-level auxiliary file: main.aux I couldn't open style file
>   IEEEconf.bst ---line 45 of file main.aux : \bibstyle{IEEEconf : } I'm
>   skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style
>   file---while reading file main.aux You've used 13 entries, 0
>   wiz_defined-function locations, 110 strings with 744 characters,

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you believe that this bst should exist?

Comment: because of what I saw when I searched for a solution... I thought that some bst file was needed to use a bibliography style... am I wrong, @Ulrike ?

Comment: Certainly a bst-file is needed. But why do you believe that this special bst exists and that it is the one you should use? Whereever you saw this name, is this a trustworthy source?

Comment: I also thought that, for standardization means, the name of bst file should be similar to the template name, like the one I am using for ACM: "ACM-Reference-Format.bst"... So, I have no idea about the right bst file for IEEEconf style.

Comment: Go to the folder `bibtex\bst` in your texsystem. There you can find lots of bst. Try them out.

Comment: As stated in the question, I am using Overleaf... In this case, I think I have to get the right file in some repository and upload, right? I went back to the starting point...

Comment: Then search on CTAN, or google for bst names.

Comment: I've already searched for it before and now, without success.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles/35047#35047

Comment: I created a file named "IEEEtran.bst" with [this content](http://www.math.md/files/download/csjm/2016/IEEEtran.bst), but I am getting the following error: `./main.bbl:108: Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> $ l.108 ...oxy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/}`

Comment: There is not need to create ieeetran.bst. It is already in your texsystem. You get the error because of the underscore. The bst either can't handle url's, or you didn't input it correctly. Create a new question with a complete example.

Comment: Is the documentclass `IEEEconf` or the older version `ieeeconf`? There are some small differences between those two. However, in the IEEEconf documentation it states that "IEEEconf changes bibliography formatting by redefining the thebibliography environment instead of by requiring the author to use a particular BibTEX style file." Can you try `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}`? Any changes?

Comment: Hi, @Ilbant . I am using a template in the Overleaf with `ieeeconf`. This `abbrv` recommendation you are doing is compliant with IEEE conference template?

Comment: I found this thing on the IEEEconf documentation. I might got  a bit confused. Is there a `IEEEconf` bibliography style? Why don't you just use `IEEEtran` or `IEEEtranS`.

Comment: I did not find any IEEEconf.bst file... so, I used IEEEtran. As I am using Overleaf, I had to create the file and put the content there. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a file named IEEEtran.bst to my Overleaf project, using [this content](http://www.math.md/files/download/csjm/2016/IEEEtran.bst).