# Label of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have a problem with my bibliography. I use as Editor TexStudio.

When I write my book reference in this format:

```
    @book{1,
    author = {Davide Gould},
    title = {Complete Maya Programming: An Extensive Guide to MEL and C++ API},
    isbn = {1558608354},
    publisher = {Morgan Kaufmann},
    Year = {2003}
}
```

In the pdf it appears like this:

[image]

While I'd want the number [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZdJf.png) as label, not the "Gou03".

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to [change the bibtex style to `numeric`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35047/29873). If you need help with that, then please provide an [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: What happens if you load the `cite` package and recompile?

Comment: Nothing happens!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @book{Gould,
    author = {Davide Gould},
    title = {Complete Maya Programming: An Extensive Guide to MEL and C++ API},
    isbn = {1558608354},
    publisher = {Morgan Kaufmann},
    Year = {2003},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

The label in the bib file has nothing to do with what is printed, whuch is decided by the bibliographic style used.

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: @SnowyNe What do you mean? The code I have given compiles and gives what you expected.

Comment: If I use \bibliography{\nameOfMyBibliographyfile} it gives me the error: Undefined control sequence

Comment: Again my code compiles. Ypu probably do not know about MWEB. The only thing you have to remember are the `\bibliography{nameofypourfile}` and
`\bibliographystyle{plain}`.. No backslash before the name of your file.