# Please suggest the .bst name

Tags: bibtex

My `.bib` file tags are follows:

```
@article{abraham,
    Author = {Abraham, Ralph},
    Date-Added = {2016-08-01 19:33:58 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-03-04 22:47:39 +0000},
    Journal = {MAPS Bull.},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {8--10},
    Title = {Mathematics and the Psychedelic Revolution: Recollections of the Impact of the Psychedelic Revolution on the History of Mathematics and my Personal Story},
    Volume = {18},
    Year = {2008}}
```

Required output should be as:

[image]

Can anyone suggest that which `.bst` file produce this output? please...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35040/35864 lists a few 'galleries' with examples, where you might find what you are looking for. But you can always use `makebst` from https://ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib and get your own style that you can then modify if necessary. And then there is `biblatex`. I know of no `biblatex` standard style that is exactly like that off the top of my head, but with a few (and maybe a few more) modifications you can get there.

Comment: What should citations look like?

Answer (score 2):

This looks very much like Chicago note style.

I do not think it is possible to produce Chicago note style using a `bst` file. You could do it if you wanted a numbered bibliography and numbered citations (i.e., [1]), but as you've shown it in your example, there are no numbers, so normally such a bibliography would use footnotes for citations.

If you are willing to move from plain `bibtex` to `biblatex`, you could produce it using the `biblatex-chicago` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abraham,
    Author = {Abraham, Ralph},
    Date-Added = {2016-08-01 19:33:58 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-03-04 22:47:39 +0000},
    Journal = {MAPS Bull.},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {8--10},
    Title = {Mathematics and the Psychedelic Revolution: Recollections of the Impact of the Psychedelic Revolution on the History of Mathematics and my Personal Story},
    Volume = {18},
    Year = {2008}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{abraham}. Filler text \autocite{abraham}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]