# How to code a particular form of bibliography by having bibitem

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have the form of bibliography for a particular journal. Now I want to code it to be able to use bibtex.

For example, I have

```
\bibitem{artin} M. Artin, On Azumaya algebras and finite representations of rings, {\it J. Algebra} {\bf 11} (1969) 532--563.
```

How can I change the style file accordingly?

Comment: `biblatex` does not generate `\bibitem`s (unlike BibTeX, which does generally produce `\bibitems`) and is generally speaking not advisable for journal submissions, so I edited your question to focus on BibTeX.

Comment: Since the programming language of `.bst` files is so unusual, very few people write them from scratch for their projects. Instead the usual way to go about is to find a style that looks similar enough and modify it. There are collections of styles like http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35040/35864 that can help you choose the base style. The code for modifications will depend both on the base style and what you want to do, so there is no catch-all answer here, but you will find many questions on this site that can help.

Comment: So far, you've shown the required formatting of one particular example (single-authored publication) of one particular entry type (`@article`). A complete BibTeX style file has to embody many additional formatting decisions, such as how to format entries of type `@article` that have exactly 2 authors, or 3 or more authors. If you can't find an existing style file that meets your requirements, I suggest you look into using the `makebst` utility of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package to create a bespoke style file that meets all of your formatting requirements.

Comment: @moewe Thanks! I will have a look at those links.

Comment: @Mico You're right. I can add other examples. Actually, I want to submit my paper to this journal, where you can find other examples: https://www.worldscientific.com/page/jhde/submission-guidelines

Comment: Are you familiar with this journal citation format?

Comment: @Astrolabe - I'm *not* familiar with this journal's formatting guidelines for bibliographic entries. From what I have seen at the end of the file `ws-jhde.tex`, I'd say that their bibliographic formatting guidelines are woefully incomplete and inadequate. Have you contacted the journal's editorial staff and asked them if they either distribute a bibtex style of their own, or at least can point to an existing style file somewhere on the 'net that implements their requirements? If not, you may need to run the `makebst` utility. Don't worry, it's lengthy, but it's not all that difficult to use.

Comment: @Mico I totally agree, it's a disaster. I haven't contacted the editorial staff yet, but I suppose that they prefer the bibitems.

Comment: @Astrolabe - Do give the `makebst` utility a shot. It's a menu-driven Q&A system, with lots of questions; its output is a bespoke bst bibliography style file. With each formatting question there's a number of possible answers, with one of the answers marked as the default. Given how incomplete the journal's formatting instructions are, you'll have to make a number of formatting choices without any official guidance. In such cases, just choose the default answer.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! That was interesting! However, I had some problems. E.g., I have to put a comma after author names, i.e., after authors box. It shoud be done under 'punctuation box authors', or something like that. I have tried 'au-com' instead of 'au-col'. But it didn't work.

Comment: @Astrolabe - One of  (many) makebst's questions is `PUNCTUATION BETWEEN SECTIONS (BLOCKS)`. You should choose `c` (for commas) as the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129524/discussion-between-astrolabe-and-mico).