# bibliographystyle{plain} to bibliographystyle{acm}

Tags: memoir, acm, bibliographystyle

I want to replace my Bibliography *plain* to *acm* (I think it fits my request).

Now I have:
`\bibliographystyle{plain}` and result

[1] Name Surname ...

I want to sort as follows:

[1] Surname, Name ... (with or without comma)

Which packages and commands do I need?

Thank you for your help and advices.

Comment: You can find some links to help choosing a style at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles. But indeed replacing `\bibliographystyle{plain}` with `\bibliographystyle{acm}` would be a good start.

Comment: I have some errors when I only change to acm Class memoir: Font command \sc is not supported. Citation `xxxxxx' on page 24 undefined. etc

Comment: So the real issue arises because you employ the `memoir` document class -- a fact you didn't mention in the main body of your posting.

Comment: \documentclass[english, a4paper, oneside]{ppfcmthesis}

Comment: @Mico sorry for that I am newbie.

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises because the `acm` bibliography style would appear to contain `\sc` (and possibly other "old") font switching commands. For instance, the BibTeX function `scapify` is defined as follows in the file `acm.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {scapify}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\sc " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

However, the `memoir` class no longer recognizes `\sc` and other oldstyle font-switching commands by default. By "old", I mean LaTeX versions up to version 2.09, i.e., prior to 1995. *Really old* by now...

The fix? Load the `memoir` class with option `oldfontcommands`:

```
\documentclass[oldfontcommands,<other options>]{memoir}
```

Do be aware that warning messages will be produced whenever an old font command -- such as `\sc` -- is encountered.

Comment: How I should edit this: 

\documentclass[english, a4paper, oneside]{ppfcmthesis}

Comment: @dotpy - Add `oldfontcommands` to the list of options.

Comment: `\documentclass[english, a4paper, oneside, oldfontcommands]{ppfcmthesis}`

thats great I have only the error

The \sc font command is deprecated. 
(memoir) Use \textsc{...} or {\scshape... } instead.

Comment: @dotpy as Mico said this is a warning and not an error, so you can ignore the message.

Comment: @dotpy - Did you notice the final sentence of my answer: "Do be aware that warning messages will be produced whenever an old font command -- such as `\sc` -- is encountered"?