# Square brackets in Bibliography with `apalike` style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I have a document with this setup:

```
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
...
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bib}
```

Which is producing Bibliography entries like:

> Batty, M. (2007). Cities and Complexity. MIT Press.

However, as [the PennState references page shows](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~surajit/present/bib.htm), I would expect something like:

> [Batty, 2007] Batty, M. Cities and Complexity. MIT Press. 2007.

What should I do to get a formulation closer to the later?

Comment: Nothing to get closer, as it is wrong. The output you get is correct.

Comment: This is what the `apa` style is like.  See [Verbal descriptions of bibliography styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24540) for a description of the basic kinds of styles available. You might want to use `biblatex` instead, since it has lots more options in one package, and they are easier to customize. See also [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091) and [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)

Comment: I switched to `biblatex` and found that it is not easier to use square brackets... it still requires a ton of code :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A style file close to the one you want is the `named` style, which is not compatible with `natbib`, however, and has nothing to do with `apa` specifications.

If you want to use it, add the following lines in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\let\@internalcite\cite
\def\cite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}\@internalcite}
\def\shortcite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##2}\@internalcite}
\def\@biblabel#1{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother
```

and then use

```
\bibliographystyle{named}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Batty:2007,
author    = {Michael Batty},
title     = {Cities and Complexity},
publisher = {MIT Press},
year      = 2007}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\let\@internalcite\cite
\def\cite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}\@internalcite}
\def\shortcite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##2}\@internalcite}
\def\@biblabel#1{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This a citation \cite{Batty:2007}

\bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Indeed this formulation obtains the Bibliography style I wish, but there are a few issues with citations in the text: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263626/author-year-citation-with-named-bibliography-style

Comment: Another issue with references overflowing the text width: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263631/how-to-force-citations-within-text-width