# How to force citations within text width

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking

I am using the `named` bibliography style with the following [citation formulation provided by karlkoeller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262458/43055):

```
\makeatletter
\let\@internalcite\cite
\def\cite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}\@internalcite}
\def\shortcite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##2}\@internalcite}
\def\@biblabel#1{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother
```

While this formulation produces the desired style, it is printing a large number of citation beyond the text width, into the margin space:

[image]

Is there a way to force these citations remaining within the text body?

Comment: You can use \sloppy, but \linebreak[3] at the front of \cite might work better.  If you had provided an NWE I would run some tests.

Comment: `\sloppy` does it, `\linebreak[3]` has no effect; please insert this as an answer. P.S.: You can use [the MWE provided by karlkoeller](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262458/43055) to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `\hfil` will expand as much as `\parendskip`, but `\hfil\linebreak[3]` doesn't seem to expand at all.

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Batty:2007,
author    = {Michael Batty},
title     = {Cities and Complexity},
publisher = {MIT Press},
year      = 2007}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\let\@internalcite\cite
\def\cite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}\@internalcite}
\def\shortcite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##2}\@internalcite}
\def\@biblabel#1{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\sloppy
yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yada
This a citation \cite{Batty:2007}

\fussy
yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yadayada yada
This a citation \hfil\linebreak[3]\cite{Batty:2007}
This a citation \hfil\linebreak[3]\cite{Batty:2007}

\bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: overline prevention]