# Problem with \bibliographystyle

Tags: bibliographies, errors, apa-style

I have a strange problem.
If I run this script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Batty:2007,
author    = {Michael Batty},
title     = {Cities and Complexity},
publisher = {MIT Press},
year      = 2007}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
This a citation \cite{Batty:2007}

\bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

on my laptop, it works perfectly. If I run it on mt PC (with the same OS and same TexMaker version with the same configuration) it shows me this problem:

[image]

If I change the bibliography style (e.g. apalike) it works on every computer, but the one I need is \bibliographystyle{named}.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Try `unsrt` instead on `named`. What would named do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I've discovered named in this post:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262404/square-brackets-in-bibliography-with-apalike-style
I was searching for something similar to "apalike". The style I need is:

[Author, year]
and "named" works exactly in this way.

Comment: The error message says that the bibliography style `named.bst` is not installed on your PC. If the same code works on your laptop, you must have somehow installed that file there. I have never heard of `name.bst`, but it appears that you can get the file from CTAN https://www.ctan.org/pkg/named (manually, it doesn't seem to be in TeX live or MikTeX). Note that this `named.bst` is extremely old and its companion `.sty` file is a LaTeX 2.09 package (not a LaTeX2e package).