# bibliographystyle

Tags: bibliographies

I was wondering which style to have a format like:  Van der Geer J. Hanraads JAJ, Lupton RA. The art of writing a scientific article. J Sci Commun 2000; 163:51-9.

when I use "acm" style, the references are comes with alphabet order, I want it appears  in the list in the order in which they appear in the text. any helps would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are countless BibTeX styles out there, a by no means complete list can be found at [BibTeX Style Examples](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html), there is also [BibTeX Style Beispiele](http://verbosus.com/bibtex-style-examples.html?lang=de). You can also use `biblatex` and modify it to your wishes.

Comment: Welcome, reading on page 49 a cite of Peter Smith, you know exactly where you have to look (S for Smith). With a chronological bibliography, you would need some time to find the entry. Choronolical entries are often used by labeling with numbers. Most commonly known as Harvard vs Vancouver style. Do you really want to mix them together and get unexpected (for the reader) results?

Comment: See also [Where can I find collections of bibliography styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35040/35864) and [Verbal descriptions of bibliography styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24540/35864)

Comment: There's a nearly infinite number of possible bibliography formatting choices. Unfortunately, you're showing us the formatted output of just one entry type -- `@article`. What about the formatting of entries of type `@book`, `@techreport`, `@misc`, and `@inproceedings`?

Answer (score 1):

I do chemistry and found that the `achemso` package is incredibly useful and formats the bibliography just right using the ACS formatting:

`\usepackage[maxauthors=3,etalmode=truncate,biblabel=period]{achemso}`