# How can I adjust the notation in the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

How can I adjust the notation in the bibliography to become [1a], [1b] [1c] etc. instead of [1]?

Comment: What do you mean exactly, i dont understnad why you want that and if it exeeds 1z it becomes 2a ? if it can help the available bibliography styles could be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35047/92620) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24572/92620)

Comment: What does the 1 in [1a] represent? The chapter? Do you have per-chapter bibliographies?

Comment: @BBM: Did you mean [1a], [1b], [1c], [2], [3] etc in the bibliography list?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than giving code fragments it is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what you're doing and it is difficult reconstruct, and hence fix, your problem from the information in your question. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: @JagathAR, yes this is what I meant, the reference [1] is 3 papers written by the same author. The three papers should be labeled [1a] [1b] and [1c]. How can I do this? [2] is the second reference etc.

Comment: @BBM: Please make you question clear so that some one came up with a solution.

Comment: @JagathAR when I write my references, they come in the bibliography as [1] ....... , [2] ...... etc. My question is how can I adjust the numbers which come automatically to be [1a] ..... [1b] .....

Comment: @BBM i think there is a lot of cases to be treated, what happened if an author has more than 26 article (after [1z]) ? what happened with multi-authors those same authors have already been referenced as alone author....

Comment: @SAM: for that we have `alphalph` package.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no MWE available for this question, I am now assuming `article` class without `natbib` package. Hence, the following sample will generate the reference as per the request:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \RequirePackage{alphalph}% You could now use more than 26 sub-refs

    \begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \newif\ifmbib\mbibfalse
    \def\@bibitem#1{\setcounter{mCtr}{0}%
           \stepcounter{enumiv}%
           \renewcommand\theenumiv{\arabic{enumiv}}%
           \global\mbibfalse\item[{[\theenumiv]}]%
           \xdef\bibCtr{\theenumiv}%
           \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#1}{\bibCtr}}\fi%
           \ignorespaces}
    \newcounter{mCtr}
    \def\mbibitem#1{\stepcounter{mCtr}%
           \ifnum\value{mCtr}=1\stepcounter{enumiv}\fi%
           \renewcommand\theenumiv{\arabic{enumiv}\alphalph{\value{mCtr}}}%
           \item[{[\theenumiv]}]\xdef\bibCtr{\theenumiv}%
           \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#1}{\bibCtr}}\fi%
           \global\mbibtrue\ignorespaces}
    \makeatother


    Citations~\cite{zero,one-a,one-b,one-c,one-d,two,three,four-a,four-b,four-c,five}.

    %Citations~\cite{one-a,one-b,one-c,one-d,two,three,four-a,four-b,four-c,five}.

    \begin{thebibliography}{10aa}
    \bibitem{zero} Zero. % This item was added at the end to check whether it works
    \mbibitem{one-a} One of One.
    \mbibitem{one-b} Two of One.
    \mbibitem{one-c} Three of One.
    \mbibitem{one-d} Four of One.
    \bibitem{two} Two.
    \bibitem{three} Three.
    \mbibitem{four-a} One of Four.
    \mbibitem{four-b} Two of Four.
    \mbibitem{four-c} Three of Four.
    \bibitem{five} Five.
    \end{thebibliography}

    \end{document}
```

Note: The command `\mbibitem{}` can be used for multi-part reference and `\bibitem{}` can be used for normal reference. Hope this helps.