# How to define multipart bibliography entries in amsrefs?

Tags: amsrefs

I would like to get something like in [How can I adjust the notation in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317273/5626), but for amsrefs. IOW, I may have a "single" entry in the bibliography, like [1], or a "group" of entries, like [2a], [2b], [2c]. How do I achieve this with amsrefs?  (Alternatively, I could convert my bibliography to BibLaTeX - I don't want to, since I have almost 300 entries there and it's a bit of work, but it's better than nothing. Using BibTeX is out of question for me.)